# Laravel-mix PostCss TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-mix, postcss-loader

I have this PHP WordPress project which uses Laravel Mix and PostCss

I am not super familiar with the setup as this was a legacy project created by a developer who left the company

The project was a few years old and I've been updating the npm packages when needed there doesn't seem to be much relevant in the documentation of the parts mentioned above when it comes to updating the version

This is the error message I am getting. The message seems a little different from a lot of answers in regards to being triggered by a .scss file compilation and using laravel-mix (as opposed to 'pure' Webpack)

ERROR in ./src/styles/index.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tried reviewing the docs for laravel mix and postcss and tried some of the answers but none seemed to work

Comment: Sounds like a flaw in that laravel-mix module. Have you filed a bug report?